# Shortcode API: How to get name that matched shortcode RegEx?

Tags: php, shortcode, api

I am looking for a way to reproduce what is described in the documentation: [An overloaded shortcode callback.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Handling_Attributes)

According to the docs, the `$atts` array will contain the string that matched the shortcode RegEx. The position inside `$atts` depends on if the callback name matches the shortcode or not. The following example is taken from the docs:

```
add_shortcode('foo','foo'); // two shortcodes referencing the same callback
add_shortcode('bar','foo');
  produces this behavior:
[foo a='b'] ==> callback to: foo(array('a'=>'b'),NULL,"foo");
[bar a='c'] ==> callback to: foo(array(0 => 'bar', 'a'=>'c'),NULL,"");
```

So I registered my shortcodes like this:

```
add_shortcode('foo', 'foo');
add_shortcode('bar', 'foo');
function foo($attributes, $content = null) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($attributes);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Unfortunately, $attributes is *always* empty, it does not contain the name of the shortcode (WP 4.0).

Is this an error in the documentation or am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forgot to run the shortcodes `[foo a='b']` and `[bar a='c']` through the `do_shortcode` filter:

```
do_shortcode( '[foo a='b'] [bar a='c']' )
```

The output of `the_content()` is filtered through the `do_shortcode`, so you can just add it into your editor instead.

Running your code I get the following output for the `$arguments` dump:

```
array (size=1)
  'a' => string 'b' (length=1)
```

and

```
array (size=1)
  'a' => string 'c' (length=1)
```

so there's no `'0' => 'bar'` part here.

But you can get the current shortcode tag from the **third** parameter of the shortcode callback ( I first heard about it in [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78204/26350) answer by @toscho )

I just checked the source and if we check out the `do_shortcode_tag` function we  will find:

```
// self-closing tag
return $m[1] . call_user_func( $shortcode_tags[$tag], $attr, null,  $tag ) . $m[6];
```

where `$tag` is the third parameter containing the shortcode tag.

So in your case you can change your callback to:

```
function foo( $attributes = array(), $content = null, $tag = '' ) {

    echo $tag; // current shortcode tag

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($attributes);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

to get information about the current shortcode tag.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcode callbacks get a third argument with the shortcode name. there's a note about this in the docs:

> Appears to always appear as third argument as of 2.9.2.

```
add_shortcode('foo', 'wpse173855_shortcode');
add_shortcode('bar', 'wpse173855_shortcode');

function wpse173855_shortcode($atts, $content, $name)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($name);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

[A look at the source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c5f9a7c26a62cbd13d70cc6fd79359e4535c965e/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L281-L287) reveals that the shortcode that was matched is always passed in.